# Do I really need to learn to write Rel xpath or Rel css selectors to work with Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I am learning to scrape data with scrapy and writing Rel xpath or Rel css selector does not feel a smart way to extract data, I tried Selectorshub 2.0 but even its relative paths were not working great and its a bit frustrating. I am looking for a smart and easy way to generate Rel xpath or Rel css selector, so i can just copy and paste it to get what i want. i mean you can do that for some elements but sometimes when i need an attribute from the element, I cant do things like I used to do in Beautiful Soup like .attrs["item"]. Please share your tips and tricks for that purpose.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you learn CSS, in my opinion it's faster to learn and you can achieve almost everything you can in xpath.

If you really don't want to learn you'll have to find some automatic data extraction software, I think scrapinghub/Zyte has something. But I think you'll learn css very fast so I would recommend that.

As help you can use Google Chrome to check the selector for the element you want to scrape. Note that this will target that exact element from the very first element. So it isn't very dynamic if the page were to change. To do this, visit the page, right click on the text you want to scrape and select "Inspect". Then follow image below.
[image]

Comment: thanks. i know the basics and how to get element and all that, i used to scrape data with BeautifulSoup but the thing is that it is slow and scrapy is way faster than Soup. That is why i started learning scrapy. Well looks like i need to learn xpath and css both. is there any other benefit of learning them besides scraping data?

Comment: Yes, you'll need CSS selectors if you'll every get into web development. Then you'll use it to style your page.